# Summing functions by relations between sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Table for counting items:

```
ID  COUNT
1   10
2   0
3   12
4   1
5   5
6   10
7   9
8   9
9   11
10  0
```

Table-pedia with info about items:

```
ID  NAME    FEAT1  FEAT2
1   Nanan   R      20
2   Meowth  S      0
3   Nanan   R      13
4   Nanan   R      12
5   Uaua    L      20
6   Bobz    R      0
7   Lawkz   S      2
8   Ughtht  L      1
9   Ughtht  L      444
...
```

Table three:

```
NAME    FEAT1  COUNT
Nanan   R      23
Ughtht  L      20
Uaua    L      5
...
```

Question is about table 3: how to make a database function that will create it? (ID cell in tables 1 & 2 is just the key to connect them.)

Unique item NAME (Table 2), FEAT1 of the item (Table 2), my COUNT of item same name (Table 1).

How do I make a relation which will check what IDs are shared by same NAME (Table 2) and then take those ID and sum their COUNT from Table 1?

Answer (score 2):

Both copied down might suit:

In A1:  `=unique(_NAME)`,
in C1:  `=sumif(_NAME,A1,_COUNT)`

Answer (score 1):

First, use a `vlookup` function to put data from table 1 alongside table 2. Something like

```
G2 = vlookup(D2, A1:B9999, 2, 0)`
```

Then insert a **pivot table** with rows of NAME and FEAT1, and value SUM of count.